# How to jump to arbitrary page of results with GetListItems call on sharepoint?

Tags: web-services, sharepoint, caml

I'm using AJAX to send a web service call to Sharepoint to retrieve list items.

I get the first page of results with:

```
    "<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'> \
        <soapenv:Body> \
             <GetListItems xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/'> \
                <listName>ListName</listName> \
                <rowLimit>10</rowLimit> \
                <query> \
                    <Query> \
                        <Where> \
                            <IsNotNull> \
                                <FieldRef Name='Title'/> \
                            </IsNotNull> \
                        </Where> \
                        <OrderBy> \
                           <FieldRef Name='Title' Ascending='True' /> \
                        </OrderBy> \
                    </Query> \
                </query> \
                <queryOptions><QueryOptions/></queryOptions> \
            </GetListItems> \
        </soapenv:Body> \
    </soapenv:Envelope>"
```

I can then use the bookmark in the results to go to the next page with:

```
    "<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'> \
        <soapenv:Body> \
             <GetListItems xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/'> \
                <listName>ListName</listName> \
                <rowLimit>10</rowLimit> \
                <query> \
                    <Query> \
                        <Where> \
                            <IsNotNull> \
                                <FieldRef Name='Title'/> \
                            </IsNotNull> \
                        </Where> \
                        <OrderBy> \
                           <FieldRef Name='Title' Ascending='True' /> \
                        </OrderBy> \
                    </Query> \
                </query> \
                <queryOptions><QueryOptions> \
                    <Paging ListItemCollectionPositionNext='" + bookmark + "'" + " /> \
                </QueryOptions></queryOptions> \
            </GetListItems> \
        </soapenv:Body> \
    </soapenv:Envelope>"
```

where bookmark is "Paged=TRUE&p_Title=BlahBlah;p_ID=5"

But I want to jump to, say, page 30, or the last page, so clearly I don't have the appropriate value for p_Title.  I've tried adding the PageFirstRow variable with various numbers, but it does not change the result.  If I omit the p_Title, I just get the first page again.  Changing p_ID does nothing.

Any ideas?

Thanks,
Joel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/lists.lists.getlistitems(office.12).aspx) suggests that this is not possible.

> The XML data returned by this method
> includes a
> ListItemCollectionPositionNext
> attribute inside the rs:Data element
> that contains the information to
> support paging. This string contains
> data for the fields in the sort and
> for other items needed for paging. You
> should consider this string internal
> and not to be modified; modifying it
> can produce unexpected results.

Sad really, but I guess the name of the attribute is accurate for it's function.